# How get clang 3.4 to compile generic lambdas?

Tags: c++, auto, lambda, c++14

The [compiler at rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode) says it's running clang 3.4, and the [clang language support page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) says that clang 3.4 supports generic lambdas, but I can't get this code to compile:

```
int main()
{
    auto genLambda = [](auto param) {};
}
```

I'm compiling with `-std=c++1y`. Compiling with `--version` results in the following, which is why I believe I'm running clang 3.4:

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It *does* say "based on 3.4", so I don't know. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f7b535c7d5ae671) handles it fine.

Comment: Using clang 3.4 on my computer with only `--std=c++1y` works with your example code. `Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)`  I'm guessing that you have a revision version on that server, whereas I have the tagged release that's newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using clang 3.4 on my computer with only `--std=c++1y` works with your example code.

`Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)`

Because your `--version` references `trunk` it's probably an SVN copy of clang 3.4 which was obtained prior to generic lambdas being added to the code base.